# Searching a table of ranges, to get the result using a random parameter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a super basic simulation. In this simulation, a random float will be chosen with RAND(), this RAND() will be compared to a table of ranges and we will get the first index of the range. You can think of this as a gacha system in a game. An example is:

**Table 1:**

| Item | MinRange | MaxRange** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 0.0 | 0.5 |
| Item 2 | 0.5 | 1 |

**Table 2 (Expected Result)**

| Random | Item Name |
| --- | --- |
| 0.3 | Item 1 |
| 0.893 | Item 2 |

Items will have varying ranges of probabilities so it is necessary to build such ranges. I can not randomly pick a value directly from the list of items, they need weights.

I am open to other ways of structuring this.

I tried different lookups and match's but it does not really work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key is *match_mode* and "sorted" range to do a lookup:

```
=XLOOKUP(A11,$C$2:$C$6,$A$2:$A$6,,1)
```

Result:

[image]